# How to send binary data in JSON format from a .Net core application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How to make an HTTP post request with data in BSON format?

In .Net we can achieve with the following code.

var bsonFormatter = new BsonMediaTypeFormatter();
response = httpClient.PostAsync(_endpoint, criteria, bsonFormatter).Result;

How to achieve the same in .net core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client to address this.